# Getting 404 Error in Spring MVC application when use @controller and @RequestMapping annotation

Tags: java, apache, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

In spring MVC application i used annotation as @Controller and @RequestMapping
when i run application getting file not found error. First time i am working on Spring MVC please help me to resolve the same.

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
      <display-name>SpringMVCwithGonTuseries</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping> 

      <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
    </web-app>
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd ">
                <bean id="HandLerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>


        <!--  User @Controller Annotation -->
          <!-- <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.controller.HelloController"></bean> -->   


      <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller"></context:component-scan>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

HelloController.java

```
package com.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController{

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        modelAndView.addObject("welcomeMeassage","Hi user welcome to the first spring mvc");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

HelloPage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> First Spring MVC Application</h1>
${welcomeMessage}
</body>
</html>
```

If i remove @Controller and @RequestMapping annotation it work fine.
Please help me to resolve same

Comment: My recommendation: Don't use "Gontu", as most of this is out of date and most of the rest is wrong. Use Spring Boot instead, and you can get a working project instantly from [Initializr](https://start.spring.io). Use Baeldung or the official Getting Started guides. (I also recommend Thymeleaf instead of JSP, but that's personal preference.)

Comment: Please remove bean defined for handlerMapping

Comment: Please show your project structure

Comment: I am trying to add image of my project directory structure but after upload just it showing below link



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/604OB.jpg

Comment: Dear Sibin plz check project structure. is there any mistake made by me.